# Fake GPS location for specific app on iPhone

Tags: iphone, geolocation

Is there a way to give an app a specific location that is not the iPhone's true location?

I.e., I don't want to block location services for an app, but rather I want to make the app think it is getting location services but that the current location is different from the phone's actual location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested any of these methods, but a quick search reveals the following apps / hacks that claim to do this:

1. [iSpoofer](https://www.ispoofer.com/ispoofer-for-pc-windows-and-macos/) - Claims to "*Easily simulate any GPS location on your iPhone/iPad/iPod*".
2. [iTools](https://www.thinkskysoft.com/itools/) - Claims to "*Perfectly fake GPS location on an iPhone / iPad*".

Source: [How to fake a GPS location on your phone](https://www.lifewire.com/fake-gps-location-4165524)

A more complicated way of doing this manually, without installing any app is also described here: [How to Fake Location on iPhone Without Jailbreak](https://www.unlockboot.com/fake-location-iphone/).

Comment: do you think these (especially the manual method) are still working with iOS 16?

Comment: @BorislavIvanov No idea. For ios 16, an online search suggests this resource - https://www.imyfone.com/change-location/fake-location-ios-15/ (again, I haven't tested any of the methods personally, so use at your own risk).